# Install Root CA certificate in mobile to use JMETER Script Recorder but showing No internet connection while running the mobile application

Tags: manual-testing, jmeter, test-strategy, mobile-applications, action-recording

I'm using the `JMeter` for `recording API logs` through `HTTP(S) Script Recorder` and I have also installed the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate` in the mobile and set the `WiFi` setting in manual setting with `port` and `Proxy hostname`.

But when I try to run the application showing the `No internet connection` error every time so is there any additional setting required for setting up the connection? (Used the `desktop IP` and `8080` port)

**NOTE:**

The error is showing some of the devices not in all devices. Does it depend on the OS or WiFi version?

Answer (score 2):

I think default port for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is `8888`

[image]

so if you didn't change it - point your mobile to use port 8888 and make sure that incoming traffic is allowed in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

Also you need to take some extra steps:

1. For iOS you need to [enable full trust for root certificates](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477)

   [image]
2. For [Android](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) you need to add the next section to your [network_security_config.xml file](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config):

   ```
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
           <certificates src="user" />
       </trust-anchors> 
   </base-config>
   ```

   then [recompile your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) and replace the .apk in the device/emulator

Comment: This is very helpful answer, Glad to help QA team.
Thanks Dmitri for sharing this.